# Create new variable Y by group: Y=X, if X is among top four observations in group; else Y=0

Tags: r

My data set has annual sales of firms from several different industries.

My variables are `YEAR`, `FIRM`, `IND`, and `SALE`.

You can replicate my dataset by running the following:

```
dt <- data.frame(FIRM = rep(letters[1:10],each=10),
      YEAR=rep(2004:2013,10), IND=rep(c(210, 330), each=50), SALE=rnorm(100, 10, 2))
```

I would like to create a new variable `TOP4` that is equal to `SALE`, if the firm's sales are among the top four in its industry for the year; else `TOP4 = 0`

In my search, I came across `tail(sort(x), 4)` that will give me the top 4 observations, but I don't know how to make it work by group `~YEAR + IND`. I have been trying to write a function like the one below, but I have not been successful.

```
    top4 <- function(x){
    for (... it should run for all YEARs) {
        for (... it should run for all INDustries) {
            if (x[YEAR,IND] == tail(sort(x[YEAR,IND]), 4)) {
                dt$TOP4[YEAR,IND] <- x[YEAR,IND]
            } else {
                dt$TOP4[YEAR,IND] == 0
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any help in either writing this function or any other better approach of solving this problem will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks,
TCS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
library(dplyr)
dt %>% group_by(IND, YEAR) %>% mutate(TOP4 = ifelse(row_number(desc(SALE)) <= 4, SALE, 0))
```

Comment: Thank you very much. One small correction. The direction of the inequality should be changed to less or equal than four (<=4).

Comment: @TCS I edited the answer accordingly. Feel free to mark the answer as accepted (checkmark) if it suits your needs.